# NameError: name 'isdigit' is not defined

Tags: python, string

HERE'S WHAT I WAS SUPPOSED TO DO:
In a school, admission number of student is a 10 digit string. First four digits represent the year of admission, next two digits represent the class in which the student took admission, and the last four digits are the serial number. Write a program to do the following:

Check whether the admission number is valid or not. An admission number is valid if it is 10 characters long and contains digits only.

If the admission number is valid, display its three components separately.

```
admn= input("enter your admn no.")
while len(admn)!=10 or isdigit(admn)==False:
    print("Please enter a valid admn no.")
    admn= input("Reenter your admn no.")
    pass
print ("your admission number is :",admn)
print ("year of admission: ",admn[:4:1])
print ("Student's enrolled Class: ",admn[4:6:1])
print ("Serial number: ",admn[:-4:-1])
```

it is not working fine somehow whatever i input tells me to reenter the admission number. please suggest where am i wrong.

Comment: What is the error of your program? post it

Comment: `while len` loops while the length is greater than zero -> you probably want while `len(...) != 10`

Comment: oml it helped me lukor i actually wrote it in the psedocode but fogot to type it in python thanks!!!!

Comment: NameError: name 'isdigit' is not defined

Comment: do `admn.isdigit()` insead of `isdigit(admn)`

Comment: thanks a ton yay i can finally run this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres correct way to do what you want:

```
admn= input("enter your admn no.")
while len(admn) != 10 or not admn.isdigit():
    print("Please enter a valid admn no.")
    admn= input("Reenter your admn no.")
print ("your admission number is :",admn)
print ("year of admission: ",admn[0:4])
print ("Student's enrolled Class: ",admn[4:6])
print ("Serial number: ",admn[6:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()`  doesn’t take any arguments so if you pass the parameters then it will return error.

So you should use dot operator (`.`) after the string variable instead, like `admn.isdigit()`